# Ng build -prod Angular 2 - Como publicar a aplicação

Tags: php, javascript, html, angular

após dar Ng build -prod ele gera arquivos para distribuição, a minha dúvida é o seguinte como posso fazer para publicar isso em um servidor PHP ou qualquer outro normal, porque quando tento pegar os arquivos gerados pelo javascript em coloca-los em outro documento html ou php, não funciona, esses arquivos funcionam sem estar em um servidor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao fazer o build de uma aplicação angular 2 os arquivos gerados podem ser utilizados em qualquer servidor web.

Ex: no Wampserve você pode copiar a pasta `/dist` do seu projeto angular para a pasta `/www` do wampserve e acessar `localhost/dist` e lá estará sua pagina em angular 2.

Obs: os arquivos gerados devem ser usados em conjunto e não separadamente pois um depende do outro para funcionar.

A melhor maneira de se trabalhar com angular 2 e PHP é estudando os conceitos de SPA (Single Page Application) e API RESTful